# Deleting a directory without looking inside

Tags: macos, command-line, file-management

I have a directory in my hard drive which causes a bug that opening this directory opens itself again and again in a loop. And this goes on until computer freezes. I have tried with several program and couldn't remove it. Is there a command line command that removes directory without ever looking inside it so, i can get rid of this file.

I am looking for any solution than formatting my hard drive, doesn't have to be command

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried repairing your drive using Disk Utility? Have you tried `rm -rf /path/to/the/directory` in Terminal?

Comment: It gives 'Input/output error'

Comment: This command gives this error     rm -rf /path/to/the/directory

Comment: So, did you try Disk Utility?

Comment: Disk utility took like 4-5 hours maybe, and i have looked up on the internet that it shouldn't have took so long because, it is only 2TB and i just stopped it. I will let it run longer in an appropriate time.

Answer (score 0):

Write a C++ code using this library

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/67y3z33c(v=vs.80).aspx

and edit that directory with the code

Comment: I don't know C++, is it possible with C

Comment: i guess there should be libraries for that too, dont worry even if you are a begginer ask question you would do it,